# IMAP batch fetch text part of messages

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

I'd like to download the text (that is mime type `text/plain`, `text/html` `text/richtext`) from UID x to UID y.

I have the UID's (and not mailbox IDs).

How can I do something like

```
FETCH 412444:412500 (BODY.PEEK[TEXT/PLAIN OR TEXT/HTML OR TEXT/RICHTEXT])
```

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  downloading *just the text*?

Answer (score 3):

After checking [RFC3501](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html), the `UID` command (section 6.4.8) seems to be able to do part of this:

> The UID command has two forms.  In the first form, it takes as its
>   arguments a COPY, FETCH, or STORE command with arguments
>   appropriate for the associated command.  However, the numbers in
>   the sequence set argument are *unique identifiers instead of
>   message sequence numbers*.  *Sequence set ranges are permitted*, but
>   there is no guarantee that unique identifiers will be contiguous.

Thus, you should be able to call:

```
UID FETCH 412444:412500 (BODY.PEEK[TEXT/PLAIN OR TEXT/HTML OR TEXT/RICHTEXT])
```